# The bubble function

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

In the finite element method and more precisely the MINI element method in two dimensions, they use a function called the "bubble function" which is related to a triangle K of the space meshing and is defined using the following basis functions related as well to the triangle K:
$$
\begin{align*}
\phi_1(X)&=1-x-y\\
\phi_2(X)&=x\\
\phi_3(X)&=y\\
\end{align*}
$$ 
Where $X=(x,y)$ is a point of the boundary of $K$. Now in all articles and books I consult, they define the bubble function as following:
$$
\phi_b(X)=27\phi_1(X)\phi_2(X)\phi_3(X)
$$
My problem is I dont get where the 27 came from, I tried to use interpolation functions but I'm not sure if the term 27 comes actually from an interpolation !! Does any one have a clue or maybe the answer ? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

It is defined that way so that its [maximum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+27*x*y*%281-x-y%29) is exactly 1: $\|\phi_b(X)\|_{\infty}=1$.